# Two annotations in a single query

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to build a query set to do a count, the query set involves three models.

`class Owner(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)`

`class Location(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
     owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)`

`class Asset(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=false)
     owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
     location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)`

I am trying to do a count for Locations for the owner and Assets for the owner, I can achieve this as two separate Querysets as follows:

`locations = Owner.objects.all().annotate(locations=Count('location'))`

`assets = Owner.objects.all().annotate(assets=Count('asset'))`

This works fine, but what I'm trying to do is get a single row for both values and build a table similar to the one below.

`| Owner  | Assets | Locations |
|--------+--------+-----------|
| owner1 |   10   |    3      |
| owner2 |   100  |    20     |
| owner3 |   70   |    50     |`

I've tried to put both annotations in a single query but I don't appear to get the right results,  the count is either the same for both assets and location or I get very large numbers which I assume because both count operations are impacting each other.

Query below gives me the same numbers for both asset and location

`queryset = Owner.objects.all().annotate(assets=Count('asset'), locations=Count('location'))`

or

Query below gives me large numbers for both asset and location

`queryset = Owner.objects.all().annotate(assets=Count('asset')).annotate(locations=Count('location'))`

I can do this directly with SQL but I'm hoping not do go down that path.

Comment: Your problem may be as a result of multiple aggregrations which would always yield wrong results, does  this: `queryset = Owner.objects.all().annotate(assets=Count('asset', distinct=True)).annotate(locations=Count('location', distinct=True))` yield the right results?

Comment: i would add to nara's comment: try doing this in the django shell and running `queryset.query` to see the SQL that django generates. it may help you figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Nara, I tried a different permutation of what you suggested which ended up working.

`queryset = Owner.objects.all().annotate(assets=Count('asset', distinct=True), locations=Count('location', distinct=True))`

Here is what it looks like from a Django shell.

```
>>> from inventory.models import *
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> queryset = Owner.objects.all().annotate(assets=Count('asset', distinct=True), locations=Count('location', distinct=True))
>>> vars(queryset[0])
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x0427B230>, 'id': 1, 'name': 'Owner 1', 'assets': 5, 'locations': 4}
>>> vars(queryset[1])
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x0427B2D0>, 'id': 2, 'name': 'Owner 2', 'assets': 3, 'locations': 4}
>>> vars(queryset[2])
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x0427B4D0>, 'id': 3, 'name': 'Owner 3', 'assets': 2, 'locations': 6}
```

As you can see that gives me both the asset and the location counts.